# Putting jQuery at the bottom of my HTML templates is inflexible

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I have been re-factoring some of my templates and have put the link to jQuery code at the bottom of my template files to keep page load speeds fast.

I also have some javascript modules that I only use on specific pages so I don't include these in the main template but rather inside the content.

Here is how the templates look....

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- navigation -->
        <nav></nav>
        <!-- end navigation -->

        <!-- main content -->
        <?php $this->load->view($module . '/' . $view_file); ?>
        <!-- end main content -->

        <!-- footer -->
        <footer></footer>
        <!-- end footer -->

        <!-- javascript dependencies -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If I add custom js code to a specific page inside the template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- navigation -->
        <nav></nav>
        <!-- end navigation -->

        <!-- main content -->
        <?php $this->load->view($module . '/' . $view_file); ?>
        <!-- end main content -->

        <script src="some custom js that uses jQuery"></script>

        <!-- footer -->
        <footer></footer>
        <!-- end footer -->

        <!-- javascript dependencies -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get errors

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

So do I have to put my jQuery and other dependencies in the document head or is there another way?

Comment: The jquery should be loaded before any jquery code is used, so the file needs to go above the code. That is why it is normally put in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the script is running before jQuery has been loaded, so it is undefined.

To fix this, just place your custom script in the line below the jQuery import and it should work.

Alternatively, put the jQuery import higher in the page so it is always above your custom scripts and it will work.

Comment: Problem is that is why it is inflexible... I have to include EVERY js snippet on EVERY page even if that snippet is used on one page... I only want to include snippets on a single page...

Comment: Not really, all you need to do is ensure jQuery is loaded before your snippets, by loading it at the top of the page for example. If you find it really annoying to do that, you can just cut jQuery loose and write all of your snippets in vanilla JavaScript!

Comment: Never! Okay, so I need to include my jQuery before my main content.

Comment: Yep, that will sort you out. Realistically if you are concerned about page loading speed it won't have a huge effect.  Minified jQuery is only 85kb, so it's smaller than the size of the average image. Loading it higher in the page will have a small effect on load speed compared to say having uncompressed images that have way too large native sizes! Hope that helps